# how to have 'find' not return the current directory

Tags: find

I'm currently trying to `find` (and copy) all files and folder structure matching a specific pattern, in a specified directory and I'm so nearly there!

Specifically, I want to recursively copy all folders not begining with a '_' character from a specified path.

```
find /source/path/with/directories -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name _\* -exec cp -R {} /destination/path \;
```

In the /source/path/with/directories/ path are machine-specific directories beginning with '_' and others, and I'm only interested in copying the others.  For a reason beyond me, the find command returns the /source/path/with/directories/ directory, and therefore copies its content, directories begining with '_' included.

Anyone have a hint as to why that is?

Thanks,

Pascal

Comment: for posterity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525004/how-to-exclude-this-current-dot-folder-from-find-type-d

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`find` returns the root path because it matches your criteria—i.e. it is a directory, and it doesn't start with `_`.

You're looking for `-mindepth 1`, I suspect:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir a
$ touch a/b
$ mkdir a/c
$ touch a/c/d
$ find a
a
a/b
a/c
a/c/d
$ find a -mindepth 1
a/b
a/c
a/c/d
```

Reference: [find manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Comment: Excellent! works as I wanted.  I had it working by adding ! -name 'files' but it felt wrong to me...

Answer (score 0):

Change from:

```
find /source/path/with/directories ...
```

to:

```
(shopt -s dotglob; find /source/path/with/directories/* ... )
```

That way `/source/path/with/directories` will not be included.

The `shopt -s dotglob` is so that `*` will also match files and directories starting with a `.` (hidden files, directories).

And the whole thing is wrapped in a sub-shell with `(...)` to limit the effect of `shopt` only within the sub-shell, otherwise you would have to undo it later with `shopt -u dotglob`.

Comment: That will fail for directory entries that start with `.`.  Don't try `.*`, either, or you'll match a whole lotta other stuff you never intended to. ;-)

Comment: Good point, updated the answer, added using `shopt`.